# How do I get a total row count of a table when the file path is in a variable?

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to count the total number of rows in table 1 in a Word document.
The document path is in a variable because it will change based on user input. The variable that contains the path is `fpath`.

How do I get the total row count of table 1 when I use the variable instead of the file path?

My code seems to fail due to `Documents(fpath).Tables(1).Rows.Count`.

```vb
Sub CountTableRows()
    Dim fpath as String  'contains file path                                                             
    Dim fdoc as Document
    Dim trows as Integer 'contains total number of rows in table
    Set fpath = "c:\folder\document.docx"
    Set fDoc = Documents.Open(fpath)
    fDoc.Activate
    trows = Documents(fpath).Tables(1).Rows.Count
    MsgBox "total rows= " & trows
End Sub
```

Comment: What the error message did you get? You already set `fDoc` to the opened file so can try `fDoc.Tables(1).Rows.Count`. You also won't need `fDoc.Activate` if you are working with the variable.

Comment: In addition to Raymonds advice I'd check the Document has at least one Table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may wish to revise your code to be more defensive, so that it does not fall over if it hits one of your hidden assumptions. (i.e. the file exists, and has at least 1 table).

```
Public Function CountTableRows(ByVal ipPath As String, ByVal ipTableNo As Long) As Long

    CountTableRows = -1
    
    Dim myDoc As Word.Document
    If Not TryOpenDoc(ipPath, myDoc) Then
    
        Debug.Print "There was a problem opening '" & ipPath & "'"
        Exit Function
        
        
    End If
    
    Dim myRowCount As Long
    If Not TryCountRows(myDoc, ipTableNo, myRowCount) Then
    
        Debug.Print "Document '" & ipPath & "' does not have Table " & ipTableNo
        Exit Function
        
        
    End If
    
    myDoc.Close
    CountTableRows = myRowCount
    ' MsgBox "Total rows =" & myRowCount
        
End Function


Public Function TryOpenDoc(ByVal ipPath As String, ByRef opDoc As Word.Document) As Boolean

    TryOpenDoc = False
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Set opDoc = Application.Documents.Open(ipPath)
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit Function
    
    Err.Clear
    TryOpenDoc = True
    
End Function


Public Function TryCountRows(ByRef ipDoc As Word.Document, ByVal ipTableNo As Long, ByRef opRowCount As Long) As Boolean

    TryCountRows = False
    If ipDoc.Tables.Count < ipTableNo Then Exit Function
   
    opRowCount = ipDoc.Tables(ipTableNo).Rows.Count
    
    TryCountRows = True
    
End Function
```

Comment: @jeremythompson and RaymundWu, thank you so much for your help. The main issue I had was that I defined the variable that referenced the word document as "Document", instead of as word.document. The other issue I had was that I didn't know how to express the command to count the rows using the variable. So, your example above answers that question: opRowCount = ipDoc.Tables(ipTableNo).Rows.Count    Thank you also for suggesting to separate the code in functions and to add controls to check for table and document existence. Very useful.